# How do get an output table or a plot of individual variables from NDSolve output

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following equations and settings:

```
Clear[koff]; koff = 5.*10^-5;
Clear[kon]; kon = 1.*10^4;
Clear[koff2]; koff2 = 1.*10^-5;
Clear[kon2]; kon2 = 1.*10^4;
Clear[kcg]; kcg = 1.2*10^-5;
Clear[ndsolKRH];
ndsolKRH =
  NDSolve[{
      D[ag[t], t] == -kon2*ag[t]*b[t] + koff2*cg[t] - kcg ag[t], 
      D[a[t], t] == -kon*a[t]*b[t] + koff*c[t], 
      D[cg[t], t] == kon2*ag[t]*b[t] - koff2*cg[t], 
      D[c[t], t] == kon*a[t]*b[t] - koff*c[t], 
      D[b[t], t] == -kon2*ag[t]*b[t] - kon*a[t]*b[t] + koff2*cg[t] + koff*c[t],
      ag[0] == 450. 10^-9, a[0] == 90.247 10^-9, cg[0] == 0, 
      c[0] == 473.75 10^-9, b[0] == 26.25 10^-9},
    {ag, a, b, c, cg},
    {t, 0, 1200000}][[1]];
```

I would like to get a table of individual numbers for cg and ag. I would also lime to be able to plot these variables vs time. At present I can do it one at a time but there must be a lot easier way.

I am doing the following:

```
Clear[solKRHfix]; solKRHfix = ag /. ndsolKRH;
```

AND THEN:

```
solKRHfix[600000]
```

Comment: Fixed formatting, but didn't spend any time working out what the unrecognized symbols are.  Please check my edit and modify as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I interpreted the input correctly,

```
koff = 5. 10^-5;
kon = 1. 10^4;
koff2 = 1. 10^-5;
kon2 = 1. 10^4;
kcg = 1.2 10^-5;

ndsolKRH = NDSolve[{
     ag'[t] == -kon2*ag[t]*b[t] + koff2*cg[t] - kcg ag[t],
     a'[t] == -kon*a[t]*b[t] + koff*c[t],
     cg'[t] == kon2*ag[t]*b[t] - koff2*cg[t],
     c'[t] == kon*a[t]*b[t] - koff*c[t],
     b'[t] == -kon2*ag[t]*b[t] - kon*a[t]*b[t] + koff2*cg[t] + koff*c[t],
     ag[0] == 450. 10^-9,
     a[0] == 90.247 10^-9,
     cg[0] == 0,
     c[0] == 473.75 10^-9,
     b[0] == 26.25 10^-9},
    {ag, a, b, c, cg},
    {t, 0, 200000}][[1]];

Plot[(# /. ndsolKRH)[t], {t, 0, 200000},
    Frame -> True,
    Axes -> False,
    FrameLabel -> {t, ToString[#] <> "[t]"},
    ImageSize -> 300] & /@
  {ag, a, b, c, cg} // Column
```

[image]

EDITED: Added Table.

```
TableForm[
 Table[(func /. ndsolKRH)[t],
  {t, 0, 200000, 20000},
  {func, {ag, a, b, c, cg}}],
 TableHeadings -> {
   Range[0, 200000, 20000],
   (ToString[#] <> "[t]") & /@ {ag, a, b, c, cg}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[koff]; koff = 5.*10^-5;
Clear[kon]; kon = 1.*10^4;
Clear[koff2]; koff2 = 1.*10^-5;
Clear[kon2]; kon2 = 1.*10^4;
Clear[kcg]; kcg = 1.2*10^-5;
Clear[ndsolKRH];
ndsolKRH =
  NDSolve[{
      D[ag[t], t] == -kon2*ag[t]*b[t] + koff2*cg[t] - kcg ag[t], 
      D[a[t], t] == -kon*a[t]*b[t] + koff*c[t], 
      D[cg[t], t] == kon2*ag[t]*b[t] - koff2*cg[t], 
      D[c[t], t] == kon*a[t]*b[t] - koff*c[t], 
      D[b[t], t] == -kon2*ag[t]*b[t] - kon*a[t]*b[t] + koff2*cg[t] + koff*c[t],
      ag[0] == 450. 10^-9, a[0] == 90.247 10^-9, cg[0] == 0, 
      c[0] == 473.75 10^-9, b[0] == 26.25 10^-9},
    {ag, a, b, c, cg},
    {t, 0, 1200000}][[1]];

{ag, a, b, c, cg} = ndsolKRH[[All, 2]];

tbl = Table[Through[{ag, a, b, c, cg}[t]], {t, 0, 1200000, 100000}];
heading = 
  Replace[Hold[{ag, a, b, c, cg}], s_ :> ToString[Unevaluated[s]], {2}] // ReleaseHold;
TableForm[tbl, TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 1200000, 100000], heading}]
```

[image: table]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Through[{ag, a, b, c, cg}[t]], {t, 0, 1200000}]
```

[image: plot]