# how to get table (with lists of arguments and values) from numerically obtained function?

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, list-manipulation

I obtained numerical solution of function
$\varphi (t)$ :

```
Subscript[l, 2] = 1
Subscript[m, D] = 1
Subscript[m, 4] = 0.5
Subscript[l, 1] = 0.5
Subscript[m, pw] = 10
Subscript[m, 3] = 0.05
Subscript[m, 12] = 0.5
g = 9.81

sol = NDSolve[
{(1/3)*(Subscript[l, 1]^2 - Subscript[l, 1]*
Subscript[l, 2] + Subscript[l, 2]^2)*
Subscript[m, 12]*Derivative[2][φ][t] + 
Subscript[l, 2]^2*(Subscript[m, 4] + Subscript[m, D])*
Derivative[2][φ][t] + Subscript[l, 1]^2*
(Subscript[m, 3] + Subscript[m, pw])*
Derivative[2][φ][t] == (-(1/2))*g*
Sin[φ[t]]*
(Subscript[l, 1] + Subscript[l, 2])*
Subscript[m, 12] - g*Sin[φ[t]]*Subscript[l, 2]*
(Subscript[m, 4] + Subscript[m, D]) + 
g*Sin[φ[t]]*Subscript[l, 1]*(Subscript[m, 3] + 
Subscript[m, pw]), φ[0] == -(Pi/2), 
Derivative[1][φ][0] == 0}, φ, {t, 0, 5}]
```

Now I would like to get a table that looks like:

$$\left\{\left\{t_ 1, \varphi\left (t_ 1 \right) \right\}, \left\{t_ \
2, \varphi\left (t_ 2 \right) \right\}, \text { ...} \right\}$$

It will allow me to receive a curve fit of that  $\varphi (t)$. It would work as/ "pretend" to be an analytical solution of that  function

So far I've managed to do a list of **only values** of the function:

$$\left\{\left\{\varphi \left(t_1\right)\right\},\left\{\varphi \left(t_2\right)\right\},\text{...}\right\}$$

I made it possible with such a code:

```
Table[Evaluate[φ[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 3, 0.1}]
```

Ive searched this forum for the answer. Perhaps the answers for that topic: [How do get an output table or a plot of individual variables from NDSolve output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56458/how-do-get-an-output-table-or-a-plot-of-individual-variables-from-ndsolve-output) may also solve my problem. However, applying them to my code hasnt succeeded.

EDIT:

As Szabolcs said I changed initial Table[] function to:

```
Table[Evaluate[{t, φ[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 3, 0.1}]
```

It returned also arguments in the list but it still doesnt look good and Fit[] command doesnt understand it:

```
{{{0., -1.5707963267948966}}, {{0.1, -1.5971972923422582}}, 
{{0.2, -1.6763634000585368}}, 
{{0.30000000000000004, -1.8079646031356074}}, 
{{0.4, -1.990731163585647}}, {{0.5, -2.221454375616052}}, 
{{0.6000000000000001, -2.493858943689834}}, 
{{0.7000000000000001, -2.797792449354243}}, 
{{0.8, -3.1193061751518516}}, 
{{0.9, -3.4419813261678978}}, {{1., -3.749226590053859}}, 
{{1.1, -4.026647876727996}}, 
{{1.2000000000000002, -4.263540926218915}}, 
{{1.3, -4.4531326077818285}}, 
{{1.4000000000000001, -4.591858870491535}}, 
{{1.5, -4.678249284050099}}, {{1.6, -4.711892284900368}}, 
{{1.7000000000000002, -4.692733698390326}}, 
{{1.8, -4.620797061710061}}, 
{{1.9000000000000001, -4.496343183956725}}, 
{{2., -4.320460237517014}}, {{2.1, -4.096023501689881}}, 
{{2.2, -3.828826631949308}}, 
{{2.3000000000000003, -3.528469355258367}}, 
{{2.4000000000000004, -3.208429680736051}}, 
{{2.5, -2.884909173445035}}, {{2.6, -2.574625419992486}}, 
{{2.7, -2.292389160658032}}, 
{{2.8000000000000003, -2.0494524968628878}}, 
{{2.9000000000000004, -1.8531009467699173}}, 
{{3., -1.7072756804683258}}}
```

Comment: Please post the code in a way that it can be copied and pasted back to Mathematica.  Use a code block, not LaTeX. Test that you can paste it back and it stays intact.  Click the [?] button on the editing toolbar if you need formatting help.

Comment: Why don't you put `{t, phi[t]} /. sol` instead of `phi[t] /. sol` in your `Table`?

Comment: It partly helped. Now I have arguments and values but output list looks strange and Fit[] function doesnt understand it.     I can send it as a code but then the typeset will be gone. Is it possible to keep the typeset just like in Mathematica and publish it as a code?

Comment: Your problem is probably that `sol` is a *list* of replacement rule lists. Try taking `sol[[1]]` or `Flatten@sol` if you are confident that there is just one solution set given. What's happening is that for each `t`, you are getting a list of the form `{{t, PhiSolution1[t]},{t,PhiSolution2[t]}...}`. In this case, there is just one solution, so you end up with lists like `{{t, PhiSolution[t]}}`.

Comment: `part = Partition[Flatten@table, 2]` then `Fit[part, {type of fit here}, x]`

Comment: @J_Nat, I checked that this is also a good solution to problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that sol is a *list* of replacement rule lists. Try taking `sol[[1]]` or `Flatten@sol` if you are confident that there is just one solution set given. What's happening is that for element of the `Table`, you are getting a list of the form `{{t, PhiSolution1[t]},{t,PhiSolution2[t]}...}`. In this case, there is just one solution, so you end up with lists like `{{t, PhiSolution[t]}}`. An illustration of what I mean:

[image]

Compare what happens when we do and don't flatten `sol`.

Comment: This is complete answer to my problem. Thank you. I wouldnt be able to figure it out by myself. For beginners like me I can only assure that if you key in   sol[[1]]   instead of    Flatten[sol]   in Table[ ] function you will get the same correct result.